# using python: how create firewall to block/drop network packets

Tags: python, firewall, iptables

Like the question stated... How to use python to block/drop packets from blacklisted host (MAC address) ... or more specific, ARP packets

I know that *inux has utilities like "iptables" that can perform this ...

is there any modules or solution in python that can apply on windows or both *inux and windows?

thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Iptables is command line tool for controling netfilter, a linux kernel module for filtering network packet. This is only for Linux. Windows have his own kernel approach, and same for BSD* system.

You might found some tools done in Python for controling one of them, but not all :) Feel free to start a new project !